# Predictive maintenance data set

Tags: data-mining, dataset, prediction, knowledge-discovery

Currently I am working on my PhD thesis which is focused on predictive maintenance and failure prediction in industrial manufacturing processes. To test my hypothesis I would like to use real-world data. I have reached a automotive company and I have requested the data from them. They are collecting data with these parameters:

Breakdown ID, Type of breakdown, Localization, date, time

I am missing the Breakdown reason information. Is it possible to do serious data mining on this data or are they useless? What would you suggest to focus on with this data? Thank you.

Comment: Noone can answer whether or not your data is useful by simply looking at the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a similiar topic. The first question that you need to ask yourself is:

**What is the target variable?** (the one that you want to predict)

Then in the next step you can start to collect data. Basically you will want to use data that is a) feasible to collect and b) non-intrusive (in the context of industrial manufacturing).

The input data can be literally anything. You will want to collect data which has a reasonable connection to the target variable.
In engineering context this could be process related data such as acceleration or energy profiles of a process.

If you indeed only have

- Breakdown ID,
- Type of breakdown
- Localization
- date
- time

Then from engineering perspective type of breakdown and maybe breakdown ID could be of interest. Localization could be a yield great prediction (as input for a classifier), yet probably because the type of breakdown and the ID are stronlgy connected to the localization.

Further you will not want to predict based on date only. The only thing left is "time". If time is the time passed since the last breakdown or the time since a car has left the factory or such, it could possibly be a good predictor as well.

Generally you can do serious data mining without knowing the reason of a breakdown. Yet you should use your domain knowledge to chose variables which are supposed to contain valuable information.

In the next steps, you will want to encode your features properly (so that they can be used as input for an algorithm) and you will want to analyze variance and correlation in the dataset as preprocessing.

Then you might want to standardize your variables and finally you will use some library of R or Python to test first algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My first idea was to predict the emerging of the failures, or find relationships between the failures so I could say that there is high / low probability, that one failure can cause the other failure or set of failures. Time parameter is the time when the failure emerged.

Comment: That sounds like a good research question and as far as I understand, you can use your data quite well for this question.